# Rename symbol on union type doesn't work when used with Partial

Tags: typescript, union-types

### Overview

I've the following code [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQFwngDgpsBKD2AbGBeYAiAzgVwEYFoBDAEwFsBLAO3WAB8NtMoAndAbgCgPxpgBVJs2BoA3h2ATgzJFABccGZwC%20nDgGN4lTCGDxcAKwCM8gS2HAxkqTPlY8RMlXQAaDiq4atOvfoBM8gAVCZhByQkQAHlNmAD5zS0lpZFsSCmpXFSA)

```
type Role = "admin" | "user";

type User = {
    role: Role;
};

const obj1: User = {
    role: "admin",
};

const obj2: Partial<User> = {
    role: "admin",
};
```

If I right click on "admin" in line 1, and then Rename Symbol I get the following result:

```
type Role = "sub-admin" | "user";

type User = {
    role: Role;
};

const obj1: User = {
    role: "sub-admin",
};

const obj2: Partial<User> = {
    role: "admin",
};
```

Notice that in second last line the value of role property is still "admin".

### My Question

How can I make sure that whenever I rename a Union's value, it changes all usages.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enum` in types & for static values that may to figurate in types, that is a way to avoid the problems like this.

P.S. If u're using a VS Code - to rename select a variable name & press `F2`

```
enum Roles {
    admin = "admin",
    user = "user"
}

type User = {
    role: Roles
};

const obj1: User = {
    role: Roles.admin,
};

const obj2: Partial<User> = {
    role: Roles.admin,
};
```

Comment: Yes I know enums can be used. That's not my question though.

Comment: But, it's a working solution for your question

Comment: @TayyabMazhar enum or enum like objects will be the only options for this question